# Skype in Eclipse via ECF

Tags: skype, eclipse-ecf

I am looking for a skype provider plugin to work with Eclipse ECF in Helios version of Eclipse.

There is only one Skype provider so far and the update site for it is down for very long. Has any one connected or code shared via any Skype provider with Eclipse?

Your suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks,
J